# facebook auto login (multiple users on same device)

Tags: facebook, authentication

i've been looking into this but haven't been able to find a definitive answer. is it possible to incorporate facebook login into my application such that the user need only login to facebook once? so the user's account on my site is tied to his/her facebook account, and when they log in to my site, they are automatically logged in with facebook as well?

the catch is that the solution can't have anything with a user's device. this is because my application is built for a kiosk-type platform, where multiple users use the same machine. when they log in to the app (which they will actually be doing through a card scanner), i want them to only have to login to facebook the first time.

is this possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't log into facebook for them, but you can access to the user's data even when they're not logged in, by requesting the offline_access permission on the first authorization.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

> In addition to the access token (the
>   access_token parameter), the response
>   contains the number of seconds until
>   the token expires (the expires
>   parameter). Once the token expires,
>   you will need to re-run the steps
>   above to generate a new code and
>   access_token, although if the user has
>   already authorized your app, they will
>   not be prompted to do so again. If
>   your app needs an access token with an
>   infinite expiry time (perhaps to take
>   actions on the user's behalf after
>   they are not using your app), you can
>   request the offline_access permission.

What you need to do is to link the user identification from your app to the facebook user id and send requests on their behalf.

Comment: thanks for your response! so you can access a user's data in offline mode, but can you do more? specifically, my app needs to be able to post a picture on the user's friend's wall. is that possible?

Comment: Yes. But make sure you let the users know that the app will be posting the picture, to avoid issues with fb privacy policies.